# Validate upload file dimensions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, validation, size, dimensions

I want to validate a file in JavaScript.
I have a form where I upload the file.

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" ><span></span>
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php print $event['id'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Schimba Imaginea"  onClick="return validateEditImageEvent()" >
```

I created a function that validates the form:

```
function validateEditImageEvent()
{
    var valid;
    valid = true;
            
    valid *= checkIsFile(document.forms["editImageEvent"]["attachment"]);   
            
            
    return valid > 0;
}
```

And a function that validates the file:

```
function checkIsFile(el){
    span = el.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    span.innerHTML="";
    if (el.value =='')
    {
        span.appendChild(eIcon("Adaugati o imagine!"));
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(el.files[0].size >= 500000)
        {
            var actsize = el.files[0].size / 1000;
            var mysize = actsize.toFixed(0);
            alert('Fisierul uploadat este prea mare. Dimensiunea maxima trebuie sa fie de 500 KB.  Dimensiunea actuala este de '+mysize+' KB.');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
                     
            var file = el.files[0];
            if( file ) {
                var img = new Image();

                img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file );

                //img.onload = function() {
                    var width = img.naturalWidth,
                    height = img.naturalHeight;

                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );

                    if( width > 2048 || height > 2048 ) {
                            
                        alert('Imaginea are dimensiunea prea mare: '+width+'x'+height+'. Maximul admis este de 2048x2048.');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                             // form.submit(); 
                    }
                //};
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
                                          

            }
        }
                
    }
        
}
```

I have a problem with the commented text : `//img.onload = function() {  };`
because when the file has the right dimensions I cannot return true, because a have to call the `form.submit()` event.
But I just want to return true.

How can I change the function to remove the commented code and to work. if I do that now, the  width and height validation doesn't work.